# Display Tag cloud of links on Google maps?

Tags: google-maps, tag-cloud

I want to display a set of link on Google maps as a cloud. I'm not sure how to go about it. I first tried using ELabels and even the google Maps API MapLabelto display labels on the map but they cant be links.How do I create a tag cloud and display it on google maps?

Answer (score 0):

use linkliberito, i think it has what you totally needed. :)

Comment: Google search not giving me any documents. Is the spelling right?Could you please provide me a link.Thank you!